# Twitter Share button dynamic URL share

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I'm trying to make a custom Twitter button that will grab the page URL of the current page when clicked, which would obviously change dependent on which page it appears on, not unlike the default share button. However, I am unsure how to pass the page URL into the button.

This is what I have thus far [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jF5N/)

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

</style>
<div id="social-share-container">
<div id="custom-tweet-button">
 <a id="tweetShare" href="https://twitter.com/share?url="+encodeURIComponent(document.URL); target="_blank">Tweet
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

It's a bit hacked together as I'm pretty unfamiliar  with JS.

Answer (score 7):

This passes the url and title to a simple pop-up box with the twitter share page:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function tweetCurrentPage()
    { window.open("https://twitter.com/share?url="+ encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+"&text="+document.title, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false; }
</script>

<a class="tweet" href="javascript:tweetCurrentPage()" target="_blank" alt="Tweet this page">Tweet this page</a>
```

If you don't want it to open in a popup box, you can use this instead of `window.open`:

```
window.location.href="https://twitter.com/share?url="+ encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+"&text="+document.title;
```

**Update:** 
 `escape()` function is deprecated, Replaced with `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: @Xarcell can you give more information about how it's not working? From your comment there is no way to know if there is actually a problem or if you just implemented it wrong. This post is now almost three years old so it's possible that Twitter has made changes to their service that would stop this from working or require an adjustment. The first place I would look is to make sure that https://twitter.com/share?url=[url]&text=[text] is still the correct format for sharing.

Comment: Works.  Escape is deprecated you can use encodeURIComponent instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest window.location - That will give you the current page url.

Problem is you're using JS inline in HTML - you can't do that like you're wanting to.

I updated your fiddle with some vanilla js to show you a better way to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/4jF5N/1/

```
var link = document.getElementById('tweetShare');
var url = window.location;

link.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    window.open("https://twitter.com/share?url="+encodeURIComponent(url));
    alert(url)
},false);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to parse anything on after url= at all though, not sure if this is a JSFiddle limitation or not.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on document.location:

location.hostname
location.pathname
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp